# Script file to run in android devices with help of the sh present in adb shell

Tags: android, linux, bash, shell

I am facing a problem in writing a shell script for android devices to be run only on sh present in the device (/system/bin/sh). 
I have written the following script

```
#!/system/bin/sh

while [ 1 ]; do
   cat /sys/kernel/debug/gpio > /dev/kmsg
   sleep 2
done
```

If I run the shell by the below command it cant find the `system/bin/sh 
root@xyz3g:/data # ./test_script.sh`
`/system/bin/sh: ./test_script.sh:` its giving No such file or directory

What could be the possible reasons for the above error.?

So if I am running this script by following command then I am getting a syntax Error .

```
test_script.sh[2]: syntax error: 'while' unmatched
```

I have confirmed the syntax but couldnt get any idea out of this.Can you please help me with this as I am an amateur in shell scripting.

1. In addition to this , may I know if there is a difference(`in regards of permissions and other applications`) if I run this script in rooted samsung devices and google released phones like NEXUS 4,NEXUS 5

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your script file marked executable?

Answer (score 5):

Thanks Below steps worked for me

Step1: Open file in notepad++

Step2: Go To Edit-->EOL Conversion-->Unix/Osxformat

Step3: Save it

Comment: Thank you for the quick easy tip, wish I could give you more points.

Answer (score 1):

in windows end of line is CR+LF

in android end of line is LF

I guess you edit the file in windows

change it to unix style may solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

change the script_file
dos2unix *script_file*